# How long it will take to see a preprint after submitting it to EarthArXiv

Tags: arxiv, preprint

Does anyone know how long it will take to see a preprint after submitting it to EarthArXiv? I cannot locate any relevant information on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no personal experience with the site, but the [Moderation Policy](https://eartharxiv.github.io/moderation.html) page states (as of version 2.5, dated May 20, 2022) somewhat imprecisely that

> When all submission requirements are met, EarthArXiv is typically able to moderate manuscripts within one week of submission. However, this is simply a guideline and time to publication can fluctuate due to needed interactions between EarthArXiv and authors, increases in submission rate, and volunteer moderator availability.

Comment: +1, though OP should note that it is currently a holiday period and so things may be slower than usual.